# hardhat deploy.js Error: could not decode result data Weird

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

```js
const { ethers, run, network } = require("hardhat")
require("dotenv").config()

async function main() {
    const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
        "SimpleStorage"
    )
    console.log("Deploying contract...")
    const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy()
    const simpleStoragetrans = await SimpleStorageFactory.getDeployTransaction()
    console.log("simpleStorage:sss:", simpleStorage)
    console.log("simpleStoragetrans:sss:", simpleStoragetrans)
    const contractAddress = await simpleStorage.getAddress()
    console.log("contractAddress:sss:", contractAddress)
    console.log("network.name:sss", network.name)
    if (network.name == "sepolia" && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        // await verify(contractAddress, [])
    }

  const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
    const sendValue = ethers.parseEther("800")
    //updatevalue
    await simpleStorage.store(sendValue)
    const newValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
    console.log(newValue)
}

async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
    console.log("verify Contract")
    // npx hardhat verify --network sepolia 0xxxxxxxxx8EbEf80F0008c16b0ABFc4D6a
    try {
        await hre.run("verify:verify", {
            address: contractAddress,
            constructorArguments: args,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Contract verify error:", error)
    }
}
main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

Error displayed on line 20：

```
const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
```

The strange thing is that it's normal for me to use the local hardhat network，**I only report an error when using sepolia。**

error desc

```
Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "retrieve", "signature": "retrieve()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.11.1)
at makeError (/Users/daiwenxiong/BEAR_FILE/PROJECT/WEB3_PROJECT/LEARN_CHAINLINK_HARDHAT/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:694:21)
at assert (/Users/daiwenxiong/BEAR_FILE/PROJECT/WEB3_PROJECT/LEARN_CHAINLINK_HARDHAT/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:715:25)
at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (/Users/daiwenxiong/BEAR_FILE/PROJECT/WEB3_PROJECT/LEARN_CHAINLINK_HARDHAT/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/interface.ts:916:15)
at staticCallResult (/Users/daiwenxiong/BEAR_FILE/PROJECT/WEB3_PROJECT/LEARN_CHAINLINK_HARDHAT/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:346:35)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at staticCall (/Users/daiwenxiong/BEAR_FILE/PROJECT/WEB3_PROJECT/LEARN_CHAINLINK_HARDHAT/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:303:24)
at Proxy.retrieve (/Users/daiwenxiong/BEAR_FILE/PROJECT/WEB3_PROJECT/LEARN_CHAINLINK_HARDHAT/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:351:41)
at main (/Users/daiwenxiong/BEAR_FILE/PROJECT/WEB3_PROJECT/LEARN_CHAINLINK_HARDHAT/scripts/deploy.js:20:26) {
code: 'BAD_DATA',
value: '0x',
info: { method: 'retrieve', signature: 'retrieve()' },
shortMessage: 'could not decode result data'
}
```

I did not find the reason in any document.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the main method

It was successful

```js
async function main() {
    // const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    //     "SimpleStorage"
    // )
    console.log("Deploying contract...")
    // const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy()
    // const simpleStoragetrans = await SimpleStorageFactory.getDeployTransaction()
    const simpleStorage = await ethers.deployContract("SimpleStorage")
    await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment()
    console.log("simpleStorage:sss:", simpleStorage)
    // console.log("simpleStoragetrans:sss:", simpleStoragetrans)
    const contractAddress = await simpleStorage.getAddress()
    console.log("contractAddress:sss:", contractAddress)
    console.log("network.name:sss", network.name)
    if (network.name == "sepolia" && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        // await verify(contractAddress, [])
    }

    const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
    //
    await simpleStorage.store(800)
    const newValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
    console.log(newValue)
}
```